# GNU Assemblyでのオペランドタイプについて

Tags: assembly

GNU Assemblyで`fild %ebx`となっているところで`operand type mismatch for 'fild'`というエラーが発生します。long(`fildl`)としてもエラーが発生します
`fild`(long)のオペランドタイプは何になるのでしょうか?

環境: ubuntu 16.04 x86_64 gccで-m32オプションで32bitとして実行

Answer (score 2):

えっと悪いこと言わないので x86 の機械語マニュアルを intel のサイトからダウンロードしてください。
そのほうが手っ取り早いです。

`fild` のオペランドは `mem16` `mem32` `mem64` なのでレジスタから値をロードすることはできません。
`fildl (%ebx)` なら通るはずです（まったく意味が違いますけど）

Comment: +1 ただしIntelのマニュアルはIntel記法を採用しているので、AT&T記法を採用しているGCC(GAS)で試すのはもう一段ハードルがあるかも。[x86アセンブラ](https://ja.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86%E3%82%A2%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9/x86%E3%82%A2%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9)

Comment: @sayuri 強く同意します(オイラ個人はどっちも読み書きできますけど)機械語入門に x86 ってのはいろんな意味でハードル高そうです。では何が入門向きかと訊ねられると困っちゃいますが。